# Wordpress Css Style does not load

Tags: css, wordpress, apache, wamp, wampserver

I am using using wamp server and I have put it online.
When I access the site from my desktop everything is fine.

When I open this site from any mobile phone the stylesheet does not load.
It's a default wordpress installation so no question of stylesheet error.

What can be the problem?

Ok Problem Solved So I have removed my ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you replaced url in wp_options table?

because url  for your css is wrong. Taking from local something like below which is wrong

```
http://127.0.0.1/design
```

Apply following query with desired changes:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace (option_value , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com')
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace 
(guid , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace 
(post_content , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace 
(meta_value , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');
```

Query taken from [here](http://www.creativedev.in/2011/12/to-move-wordpress-site-on-live-server/)